# How can I use borb to extract an image from PDF and its coordinates on a page, and then paste it into the desired coordinates?

Tags: python, pdf, borb

I need to extract images from a PDF document and their coordinates, and then paste this image into the new coordinates.

In `borb`, you can extract images as follows:

```
I: ImageExtraction = ImageExtraction()

# load
doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
with open("test_image.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
    doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [I])

# check whether we have read a Document
assert doc is not None

print(I.get_images())
```

At the output we get a dictionary with images:

```
{0: [<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=660x660 at 0x1A03AC5FEE0>]}
```

And how to get the coordinates of this image and its dimensions, I do not know.

In addition, in `borb` you can insert an image as follows:

```
# set a PageLayout
layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

# add an Image
layout.add(
    Image(
        I.get_images()[0][0],
        width=Decimal(237.72),
        height=Decimal(237.72),
    )
)
```

However, in this construction, you cannot select coordinates to insert an image. Perhaps you can choose some kind of `PageLayout` in which you can adjust its coordinates, but I do not know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`

`ImageExtraction` is meant to extract images, not their meta-information (such as their coordinates).

You would need to write your own implementation of `EventListener` in order to get the job done.

You can check out how `ImageExtraction` works to get a better idea of how it works.

Essentially, it listens to `ImageRenderEvent` objects being processed by the PDF parser logic.

`ImageRenderEvent` has a few methods that might be useful to you:

- `get_x()`
- `get_y()`
- `get_width()`
- `get_height()`

So, by creating your own `EventListener` and processing `ImageRenderEvent` you will be able to extract the images and their coordinates.